# Prime Faces 3.3.1 Today button Disabled

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have the calendar widget in my xhtml:

```
<p:calendar pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" navigator="true" id="endDate" for="endDate" readonlyInput="true"
                        mindate="#{manageMarketingProgramsBean.currentDate}" showOn="button" showButtonPanel="true">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" timeZone="America/New_York" />
                    </p:calendar>
```

The "Today" and "Done" button shows up but the Today button is disabled, could you please let me know what could be issue?

Prime Faces Calendar:

[image]

Comment: Given that the user cannot set a date because the widget is defined as "readOnlyInput", I don't see why he should be able to set "Today" date.

Comment: You mean to say if I change readOnlyInput="false" then the Today button will be enabled?

Comment: are you sure that today button is disabled. i think its just faded effect. if you wanna get rid of button panel just set showbuttonpanel to false. if you wanna keep them but disable them i guess css is the way to do.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, when you click the 'today' button,the color where is today will be change for easy to Recognized。
I means it will change from blue  to black.
But it never write the date  to the '' tag.